# Чтение из файла и ошибочное склеивание первых строк при записи

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы

У меня есть код, который пишет все строки в обратном порядке из файла In.txt в Out.txt

```
with open('In.txt', 'r') as In, open('Out.txt', 'w') as Out:
    for line in reversed(In.readlines()):
        Out.write(line)
```

Пример файла In:

```
ozpqgfjavi
vqgsp
kdot
ezoqeyznn
wxgkwlr
wp
```

И его Out:

```
wpwxgkwlr
ezoqeyznn
kdot
vqgsp
ozpqgfjavi
```

**По какой причине последние строки могут склеиваться в одну?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, что в последней строке исходного файла нет перевода строки. Строки считываются из файла вместе с символами новой строки.
Как решение могу предложить обрезать символ новой строки и добавлять  его при записи: `Out.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')`